# CSS - Negative Margin To Remove Parent's Padding

Tags: css, padding, margin, margins

Is it a good practise to use negative margins to remove padding of wrapper element?

For example, which of the following code pieces is better to use?

```
<div style="padding: 5px;">
 Shortened width string
 <div style="margin: 0 -5px;">Full width string</div>
 Shortened width string
</div>
```

or

```
<div>
 <div style="padding: 5px;">Shortened width string</div>
 <div>Full width string</div>
 <div style="padding: 5px;">Shortened width string</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just declare `padding:5px 0;` so you don't have horizontal padding? Though I would argue that it's perfectly fine to use negative margins, that's what they're made for but if you can avoid them in the first place, do so.

Comment: But in the example I need horizontal padding for so called 'Shortened width string'.

Comment: Why not just wrap it in another element and give it padding?

Comment: BTW, I will still argue that negative margins are perfect for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's bordering on being a hack. As long as it's used with restraint thpugh, I would say it's ok. The key is to make sure it's easy to read and understand. Add comments if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

The second is far superior. Negative margins should be avoided because they will cause you problems in IE.

Comment: Adding position:relative; helps IE with properly displaying negative margins. After that you only have to fix the issues caused by position:relative; itself :D. (Triggering hasLayout helps)

Answer (score 0):

negative margin its hide the div…. Here is trick
use zoom:1, position: relative

Here is Example

**Problem:**

```
.container{
padding: 20px;
}
.toolbar{
margin-top: -10px ;
}
```

in IE red area of toolbar div hide itself. even we are using zoom: 1. to get rid of this problem we need to add position: relative too.

**Solution:**

so your css class will become

```
.container{
padding: 20px;
}
.toolbar{
margin-top: -10px ;
zoom: 1;
position: relative;
}
```